# C++ SigSegv from multimap read using shared_ptr, this and Polymorphism

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, polymorphism, this, shared-ptr

So, I'm trying to code a scheduler for tasks.

My scheduler is using a multimap like follows:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<Task> TaskPtr;
typedef std::pair <long, TaskPtr> Task_Pair;
[...]
std::multimap<long, TaskPtr> tasks;
```

I did this as I'm using specific classes for each Tasks, all inheriting from Task.

When I first insert them (as follow):

```
this->insertTask(new WifiParseTask());
```

Using this method:

```
void Scheduler::insertTask(Task* task) {
    TaskPtr ptr(task);
    this->tasks.insert(Task_Pair(task->getNextStartingMoment(), ptr));
}
```

It works just fine and the WifiParseTask executes well.

The problem is, I want a task to put itself back in the tasks multimap when it stops. What I use is:
-To start a task in the scheduler:

```
void Scheduler::dispatch(std::multimap<long, std::shared_ptr<Task>>::iterator taskPair) {
    long startTime = std::floor(taskPair->first/10);
    if(startTime <= App::getCurrentTime()) {
        TaskPtr task = taskPair->second;
        this->tasks.erase(taskPair);
        task->run();
        App::getInstance()->getScheduler()->setStatus(Status::ON);
    }
}
```

-When the task finishes:

```
void WifiParseTask::stop() {
    super::stop();
    std::cout << "Stopped task Wifi Parsing" << "\n";
    App::getInstance()->getScheduler()->insert(this); 
}
```

And this gives me a sigsev whenever my scheduler tries to execute the Task again (so when it runs "dispatch" on the pair inserted using "this"). I'm guessing it comes from "this" in the insert, that somehow does something wrong. I found a way around:

```
App::getInstance()->getScheduler()->insert(new WifiParseTask(this->startingMoment));
```

This somehow does a similar thing, except that instead of using still the same task, it creates a "copy" of it, and it works. The thing is, I can't see why it's not working when I call "this", as "this" should be an instance of WifiParseTask, exactly like a "new WifiParseTask" is, so why is "this" not working ? Am I missing something ?

Thanks guys.

Comment: You should use coroutines for the tasks.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I don't because I don't need preemption, and considering I'm novice in C++ and this should end in an embedded system with very limited resources, I chose the "easy way" which in the end is not easier.. Would it still be better to use coroutines ? If so why/how ? Do you have an useful link for me to start from ? :)

Comment: Coroutines don't do preemption. They deal with tasks stopping and restarting. And they have 0 overhead if you do it right.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow the thing is, I don't need any stopping / restarting, all I want is my task to "reset" and to reinsert itself in my tasks multimap. So I don't need to stop it nor to restart it, just to finish it, reset it and reinsert it in my multimap. Also, I'm using c++14 which doesn't support coroutines..

Comment: Do you understand why the problem occurs? You can't create more than one shared_ptr from the same object - you have to create shared_ptrs from other shared_ptrs (except for the first one) so they know about each other.

Comment: I suggest never, ever take a raw pointer and wrap it in a shared_ptr.  Use the convention that raw pointers are never ever owning pointers. That'll save your bacon.

Comment: When the Task_Pair in `dispatch()` goes out of scope the Task gets deleted. You have to reinsert the `shared_ptr` into the map, not the task itself.

Comment: Ohh okay I got it, thank you very much guys, tbh I'm really novice in C++ and pointers, and couldn't even see why the problem was occuring. Now I see why and I'll fix it! Thanks alot!